# OpenGL LookAt function: is the up vector arbitrary?

Tags: c++, opengl, viewmodel, transformation

I am trying to understand the `glLookAt` function.

It takes 3 triplets. The first is the eye position, the second is the point at which the eye stares. That point will appear in the center of my viewport, right? The third is the 'up' vector. I understand the meaning of the 'up' vector if it is perpendicular to the vector from eye to starepoint. The question is, is it allowed to specify other vectors for up, and, if yes, what's the meaning then?

A link to a graphical detailed explanation of `gluPerstpective`, `glLookAt` and `glFrustum` would be also much appreciated. The official OpenGL documentation appears not to be intended for newbies.

Please note that I understand the meaning of up vector when it is perpendicular to eye->object vector. The question is what is the meaning (if any), if it is not. I can't figure that out with playing with parameters.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Every answer has a bit of useful information. And my question is answered. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works as long as it is "sufficiently perpendicular" to the up vector. What matters is the plane between the up-vector and the look-at vector.

If these two become aligned the up-direction will be more or less random (based on the very small bits in your values), as a small adjustment of it will leave it pointing above/left/right of the look-at vector.

If they have a sufficiently large separating angle (in 32-bit floating point math) it will work well. This angle needs usually not be more than a degree or so, so they can be very close. But if the difference is down to a few bits, each changed bit will yield a huge direcitonal change.

It comes down to numerical precision.

(I'm sure there are more mathematical terms & definitions for this, but it's been a few years since college.. :)

**final word:** If the vectors are parallel, then the up-direction is completely undefined and you'll get a degenerate view matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Will you please look at my comment to thecoshman's answer? Is this what you mean?

Comment: What he is saying is that if your up vector is (0,1,0) and you decide to aligned you eye and object so that the normal of eye->object is (or very close to) (0,1,0) you will find that the camera could spin or rotate to a undefined angle. I  have found though that in practice, that this does not happen, I never align the two enough to get into this problem.

Comment: @Armen: Correct. And as that projection gets smaller (as the up and lookat vector becomes colinear) the projection's direction (which is what matters) will change  abruptly with small changes in either vector. It is only then that you'll be getting problems.

Answer (score 3):

The up vector lets openGL know what way your have your camera.

Think in the really world, if you have to points in space, you can draw a line from one to the other. You can then align an object, such as a camera so that it points from one to the other. But you have no way of knowing how you object should be rotated around this axis that the line makes. The up vector dictates which direction the camera should be standing.

most of the time, your up vector will be (0,1,0) which means that the camera will be rotated just like you would normally hold a camera, or if you held your head up straight. if you set your up vector (1,0,0) it would be like holding your head on its side, so from the base of your head to the top of your head it pointing to the right. You are still looking from the same point (more or less) to the same point, but your 'up' has changed. A look vector of(0,-1,0) would make the camera be up side down, like if you where doing a hand stand.

One way you could think about this, your arm is a vector from the camera position (your shoulder) to the camera look at point (your index finger) if you stick you thumb out, this is your up vector.

This picture may help you http://images.gamedev.net/features/programming/oglch3excerpt/03fig11.jpg

**EIDT**

Perpendicular or not.

I see what you are asking now. example, you at (10,10,10) looking at (0,0,0) the resulting vector for your looking direction is (-10,-10,-10) the vector perpendicular to this does not matter for the purpose of you up vector glLookAt, if you wanted the view to orientated so that you are like a normal person just looking down a bit, just set you up vector to (0,1,0) In fact, unless you want to be able to roll the camera, you don't need this to be nay thing else.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still don't understand what hapens if the up vector is NOT perpendicular to the vector from eye to object

Comment: Suppose A is the plane perpendicular to eye->object vector. Are you  saying that only the projection on plane A of up vector matters?

Comment: erm... let me think here. yes... I think. All I can say for certain is that eye->object points really steeply up or down, the same up vector still works. I do not have to work up what is perpendicular to my look vector, if this is needed by openGL then it is working it out for it self (for you)

Comment: Armen: then you'll still be looking in the same direction, but perhaps as if you're upside down, or lying on your side.

Answer (score 2):

In this website you have a great tutorial

<s>http://www.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html</s>

http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~buffa/cours/synthese_image/DOCS/www.xmission.com/Nate/tutors.html

Download the executables and you can change the values of the parameters to the glLookAt function and see what happens "in real-time".

Comment: And as always with linked content: "Error 404 - Document not found"

Comment: @KromStern, thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer with a new link.

Answer (score 1):

The up vector does not need to be perpendicular to the looking direction. As long as it is not parallel (or very close to being parallel) to the looking direction, you should be fine.

Given that you have a view plane normal, N (the looking direction) and a up vector (which mustn't be parallel to N), UV you calculate the actual up vector which will be used in the camera transform by first calculating the vector V = UV - (N * UV)N. V is in turn used to calculate the actual up vector used by creating a vector which is perpendicular to both N and V as U = N x V.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is arbitrary, which lets you make the camera "roll", i.e. appear as if the scene is rotating around the eye axis.

Comment: I mean I know that it is arbitrary as long as it is perpendicular to the eye axis, but what about when it's not? I still don't imagine the meaning...